# How to get and use source of grouping in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, grouping, linq-group

I'd like to use parameter "o" (the source object) in the result of grouping, as so:

```
return (from o in objects
        group o by MySpecialConverter(o) into g
        select new Group
        {
            Key = g.Key,    
            Items = g.ToList(),         
            Source = o, // Error: The name 'o' does not exist in the current context.
            ...
        }).ToList();
```

However, I am not able to access "o" in the new group.

Comment: You've grouped your data, so `o` no longer means anything. What were you hoping to put into `Source` (that isn't already held in `Items`)?

Comment: thank you for the comment, I completed the post with the error message "The name 'o' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @JohnWu Presumably "o" would be 'all the times', thus being in *addition to* the 'items for this group'..

Comment: Yes, @JohnWu, you are absolutelly right. "o" means nothing and there is not one instance of "o" after grouping. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @g_m in that case is there still a question? :)

Comment: I have no more questions. My concept of using "o" in this place was unfounded. Thank you for your support. I'm sorry, my mistake in thinking :(

Comment: use this Source = g then you find your desired elements here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the grouped element rather than using the used element in group statement.

```
   return (from o in objects
            group o by MySpecialConverter(o) into g
            select new Group // Create Group class with the data types and  object bellow 
            {
                Key = g.Key,    
                Items = g.ToList(),         
                Source = g // used the grouped element here for selection 
            }).ToList();
```

Or if you want to get any number of element or first element or last element you can use the let key word.

```
return (from o in objects
                group o by MySpecialConverter(o) into g
                let oLocal = g.FirstOrDefault() 
                select new Group // Create Group class with the data types and  object bellow 
                {
                    Key = g.Key,    
                    Items = g.ToList(),         
                    Source = oLocal // used the grouped element here for selection 
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: The second option is great, thank you! I thought there was no answer, but it turns out that you found it. I like it because that's what I needed in my solution.